# Two Way Data Binding Angular 2 in Electron not working

Tags: angular, electron, electron-forge

I used electron-forge to create a new electron project that uses angular 2

`npm install -g electron-forge
electron-forge init -t angular2`

Then I added `@angular/forms`

`yarn add @angular/forms`

Then I edited the app.components.ts file to look like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'App',
  template:
  `<div>
    <h2>Welcome to {{name}} Angular2!</h2>
    {{name}}
    <input [(ngModel)] = "name">
  </div>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public name = 'electron-forge';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('component initialized');
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Two way binding is not working...when I change the text in my input control, the  name filed is not changing

What am I missing?

Comment: Seems to be working fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/1PJrd4zT5OXbLdccLShL?p=preview  you must have an error elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

I had to load zone.js and reflect-metadata in index.html instead of bootstrap.ts. So when I did this

```
  <script src="../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap.ts"></script>
```

This worked. I had to remove this

```
import 'zone.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

From bootstrap.ts

Comment: We do not reference a bootstrap.ts. Instead we have a reference to system.src.js which loads it's systemjs.config.js and in our case it's not working... Any help is welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since it might be because you forgot to add FormsModule in the module.ts file.Check your app.module.ts

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...
imports: [ ..., FormsModule, ...]
```

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298011/angular-4-cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input/43298039)